# Difference between returns and printing in python?

Tags: python

In python I don't seem to be understanding the return function. Why use it when I could just print it?

```
def maximum(x, y):
    if x > y:
        print(x)
    elif x == y:
        print('The numbers are equal')
    else:
        print(y)

maximum(2, 3)
```

This code gives me `3`. But using return it does the same exact thing.

```
def maximum(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return x
    elif x == y:
        return 'The numbers are equal'
    else:
        return y

print(maximum(2, 3))
```

So what's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 33):

**The Point**

return is not a function. It is a control flow construct (like `if` `else` constructs). It is what lets you "take data with you between function calls".

**Break down**

- `print`: gives the value to the *user* as an output string. `print(3)` would give a string `'3'` to the screen for the user to view. The program would lose the value.
- `return`: gives the value to the *program*. Callers of the function then have the actual data and data type (bool, int, etc...) `return 3` would have the value 3 put in place of where the function was called.

**Example Time**

```
def ret():
    return 3

def pri():
    print(3)

4 + ret() # ret() is replaced with the number 3 when the function ret returns
# >>> 7
4 + pri() # pri() prints 3 and implicitly returns None which can't be added
# >>> 3
# >>> TypeError cannot add int and NoneType
```

Answer (score 12):

What would you do if you need to save printed value? [Have a look at good explanation in docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) and cf.:

```
>>> def ret():
    return 42

>>> def pri():
    print(42)


>>> answer = pri()
42
>>> print(answer)         # pri implicitly return None since it doesn't have return statement
None
>>> answer = ret()
>>> answer
42
```

It also is no different from `return` statement in any other language.

Answer (score 4):

For more complex calculations, you need to return intermediate values.  For instance:

```
print minimum(3, maximum(4, 6))
```

You can't have `maximum` printing its result in that case.

Comment: `print minimum(3, maximum(4, 4))` does not work in OP's version :-(

Comment: @eumiro: Isn't that exactly the point of RichieHindle's answer?

Comment: @Tim: Richie's example works with the second OP's version. Mine not.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that the interactive command line isn't the only place methods will be called from. Methods can also be called by other methods, and in that case `print` isn't a usable way to pass data between them

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it depends on what you need the function to do. If the function specification state that it will print out max term, then what you have is fine. What generally happens for a method like this is that the method should return the actual value which is larger. In the case they are equal, it doesn't matter which value is returned.