# How To Loop Over A List In Python

Tags: python, list, loops

How do I loop over a list in Python. I tried using `for ch in sample_list` but it only goes through one item in the list.

```
sample_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'hello']
for ch in sample_list:
       if ch == 'hello':
              return ch
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: `return` terminates the function, you want `print` (or `yield`)

Comment: please read that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881434/difference-between-returns-and-printing-in-python

Answer (score 2):

`return` terminates the function, to avoid this you could use `print` (or `yield`; which creates a generator):

```
>>> sample_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'hello']
>>> for ch in sample_list:
...     if ch == 'hello':
...          print(ch)
... 
hello
```

However, for this particular example you should be using `any()` or `list.count()` (depending on exactly what you want to do next):

```
>>> any(item == 'hello' for item in sample_list)
True
>>> sample_list.count('hello')
1
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Chris_Rands says, you can use yield.

```
def loopList():
    sample_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'hello']
    for ch in sample_list:
        if ch == 'hello':
            yield ch
```

You should be aware that the yield return a generator in place of a list.

However you can also create a new list with results.

```
def loopList():
    sample_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'hello']
    results = []
    for ch in sample_list:
        if ch == 'hello':
            result.append(ch)

    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sample_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'hello']
out = []
for ch in sample_list:
    if ch == 'hello':
        out.append(ch)

return out
```

Apparently `return` statement is mostly used in a function to return the control to the caller Function
Unless you are using it within a function. You would rather use print function

I hope this helps

Comment: can you see the diff between yours and @Diblo's solution on returning? change that and i will vote it up

Comment: @AriGold , scrapped that part off, hadn't seen that yet - Thanks

Comment: whats happens if that is your list: ['hello', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'hello'], what would be the return? change that issue please

Comment: so we need to append all the occurrences of the word 'hello' to a say a list. Got that. i think it would be the same as the @Diblo's solution