# Magic func __str__ generating Type Error in output when used with `print` versus `return` command

Tags: python, class, return

I wanted to understand why the output is returning an error for a certain class of object defined in the code for `__str__` command. The Type Error is generated when the `__str__` is used with print vis-a-vis return command

```py
class Card():

    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        print (f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}')
```

The subsequent commands are as follows -

```py
test_card = Card ('Hearts',"Three")
print (test_card)
```

The output prints as follows -

```
Three of Hearts
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError
                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-55-483c6e59f50e> in <module>
      1 test_card = Card ('Hearts',"Three")
----> 2 print (test_card)

TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I change the `__str__` function to `return f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}'` , the output is simply **Three of Hearts**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong, and you have already found the fix -- the magic `__str__` function is supposed to **return** the string, not **print** the string and return `None`.

Comment: I think this question has been [addressed enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/750136)...

Comment: Posting a link to another answer that I found quite useful especially for novices like myself (3 weeks into learning Python with no prior programming experience) https://stackoverflow.com/a/15441904/13218820