# Iteration through a dictionary using a function

Tags: python

why does does  code1 output all the values in the dictionary and  code2 only outputs one item

my code1:

```
resources = {
"water": 300,
"milk": 200,
"coffee": 100, }                                                                             
def available(dict):
    for k,v in dict.items():
        print(f'{k}:{v}')

available(resources)
```

output1:

```
water:300
milk:200
coffee:100
```

my code2

```
resources = {
"water": 300,
"milk": 200,
"coffee": 100,}                                                                             
def available(dic):
    for char in dic:
        return f'{char}:{dic[char]}'                                  
print((available(resources)))
```

output2

```
water:300
```

Comment: ```return``` marks the end of the function. As soon as you do that, the function has ended

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `dict` as a variable/parameter name, it's a builtin. This can  easily cause confusion and bugs

Comment: it because of return command. it just return one value from your function.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881434/difference-between-returns-and-printing-in-python help?

Answer (score 3):

In `code1` you are using `print` which is not going to terminate the function, while on `code2` you use `return`. The `return` statement terminates immediately the function execution and returns that value.

If you want to return all values in `code2` and print them in the same way as in `code`` use the following:

````py
resources = {
"water": 300,
"milk": 200,
"coffee": 100,}                                                                             
def available(dic):
    return [f'{char}:{dic[char]}' for char in dic]

# here we join all the elements in the list using '\n'
print('\n'.join(available(resources))) ```
````

Answer (score 2):

`return` keyword is used to mark the end of the function. So your function ends when `return` statement is executed. Then, only one element is iterated before `return...` so only one value is printed.

What you are probably looking for is

```
def available(dic):
    return [f'{char}:{dic[char]} for char in dic]'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `my code2` you are calling `return` instead of `print`.

If you want to return the string printed from `my code1`, modify `my code2` to look like:

```py
resources = {
"water": 300,
"milk": 200,
"coffee": 100,}
                                                                             
def available(dic):
    s = ''
    for char in dic:
        s += f'{char}:{dic[char]}\n'
    return s
                                  
print((available(resources)))
```

Answer (score 0):

it because of return command. it just return one value from your function. you can test this with this code:

```
resources = {
"water": 300,
"milk": 200,
"coffee": 100,}                                                                             
def available(dic):
    for char in dic:
        print( f'{char}:{dic[char]}')                                 
available(resources)
```