# How do I store and then call strings and functions from the same dictionary?

Tags: python, string, function, dictionary

I've been trying to store and then call a string and/or a function inside a dictionary.

#### First example

```
def mainfunction():
    dict = {
        'x' : secondfunc,
        'y' : 'hello world'
    }
    while True :
        inpt = input('@')
        dict[inpt]()
    
def secondfunc():
    print('hi world')

mainfunction()
```

This works only if I input the key 'x'.
If I try to input key 'y', I get this error.

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Also, the problem with this method is that it can't make a default answer.

#### Second example

```
def mainfunction():
    dict = {
        'x' : secondfunc,
        'y' : 'hello world'
    }
    while True:
        inpt = input('@')
        z = dict.get(inpt, 'Default text')
        print(z)
        
def secondfunc():
    print('hi world')
    
mainfunction()
```

This method works for key 'y', but for key 'x' it prints something to the effect of:

```
<function secondfunc at 0x7ab4496dc0>
```

I'm trying to make it so that whichever value I input, it will either print a default value, print a string, or execute a function. All depending on the key input.

#### Last example

The only solution I've found is that which uses `if` statements.

```
def mainfunction():
    dict = {
        'x' : secondfunc,
    }
    dict2 = {
        'y' : 'hello world'
    }
    
    while True:
        inpt = input('@')
        z = dict2.get(inpt, 'Default text')
        if inpt == 'x':
            dict[inpt]()
        else:
            print(z)
        
def secondfunc():
    print('hi world')
    
mainfunction()
```

This solution takes more code than I would like it to, and it also requires an `if` statement specific to the dictionary given, which takes more time.
Is there no better way to do this?

Comment: It's exactly as the error says: strings are not a kind of thing that you call. Can you think of something that you *can* call (hint: maybe the other kind of thing currently being stored?) that could give you the desired string when it is called (hint: maybe by `return`ing it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a string itself, you need to store a *function returning a string* in the dictionary.

Most simply this can be done as an anonymous function using the `lambda` syntax:

```
answers = {
    'x': secondfunc,
    'y': lambda: 'hello world'
}
```

(It's bad practice to name this dictionary `dict`, because it shadows the built-in `dict`, so I'll use a better name here.)

Of course, `secondfunc` should not *print* a string, but *return* a string, as well, since printing is already the job of `mainfunc` (see also: [Difference between returns and printing in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881434/difference-between-returns-and-printing-in-python)):

```
def secondfunc():
    return 'hi world'
```

Now, `print(answers['x']())` and `print(answers['y']())` are working equally.

To create a default answer with the dictionary `.get()` method, it also needs to be a function returning a string:

```
def mainfunction():
    answers = {
        'x' : secondfunc,
        'y' : lambda: 'hello world'
    }
    while True:
        inpt = input('@')
        z = answers.get(inpt, lambda: 'Default text')()
        print(z)
```

Comment: Thank you, eliminates the need for IF statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `callable()` function to test if the dictionary value is a function. If it is, call it, otherwise just print the value itself.

```
def mainfunction():
    dict = {
        'x' : secondfunc,
        'y' : 'hello world'
    }
    while True:
        inpt = input('@')
        z = dict.get(inpt, 'Default text')
        if callable(z):
            z()
        else:
            print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `callable()` built-in function to test if the given object is callable.

```
z = dict2.get(inpt, 'Default text')
if callable(z):
    z()
else:
    print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance()` to check whether it's a `FunctionType` or not:

```
from types import FunctionType

def mainfunction():
    d = {
        'x': secondfunc,
        'y': 'hello world'
    }
    while True:
        inpt = input('@')
        res = d.get(inpt, 'default')
        if isinstance(res, FunctionType):
            res()
        else:
            print(res)

def secondfunc():
    print('hi world')

mainfunction()
```